# Carousel not automatically showing when page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel

i've created a carousel using the w3schools guide and i managed to have the carousel working with the images as i wanted exacept, everytime i refresh the page the carousel is not shown automatically. I would have to manually select one of the rounded icons of the carousel for it to appear and i dont want that. I just want the carousel to show immediatly when the page is loaded.

html code:

```
<section id="portfolio">
        <h2> My <span class="text-primary">Projects</span></h2>
    
    <div class="slideshow-container">

        <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
        <div class="mySlides fade">
          <div class="numbertext">1 / 2</div>
          <img src="images/c1.jpg" style="width:100%">
          <div class="text">Application Images</div>
        </div>
      
        <div class="mySlides fade">
          <div class="numbertext">2 / 2</div>
          <img src="images/c2.jpg" style="width:100%">
          <div class="text">Application Images 2</div>
        </div>
      
        <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
      </div>
      <br>
      
      <!-- The dots/circles -->
      <div style="text-align:center">
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
      </div>
      
    
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Hide the images by default */
.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}
```

javascript:

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

with which browser are you opening it? I just tried in chrome and with two random images and it worked without any problem, otherwise it may be a problem with the photos

Comment: You will get comment privileges at rep 50. Until then, when you are answering, please answer completely. I'd recommend you to delete this post to avoid negative rep.

Comment: Hi. I'm using chrome but, i've added the carousel section to the bottom of my page. Could that be the problem?